# Error when launching Meteor tutorial on Nitrous.io

Tags: meteor, nitrousio

I try to launch the meteor tutorial on [Nitrous.io](https://www.nitrous.io).

When I use it from my house, its' **ok**.

When I use it from my corporate office, it's **ok**.

I think that's because of proxy,i 've tried to configure `environments variables` like `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` but it dosnt works.

Answer (score 1):

try to use the ip instead of the webadress 54.225.85.97 or change http to https in the browser

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here :
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Meteor-behind-a-proxy

Thank's.

Pierre